# Two tables of content

Tags: table-of-contents

See the min expl below. I would like to have two ToC: one giving only the rough structure of the document and a second one giving all the details down to subsubsections. The code pasted below should do just that but the second ToC is not displayed which I do not understand.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}          
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}       

\tableofcontents

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents (detailed)}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}          

\tableofcontents

\chapter{XXX}
\section{YYY}
\subsection{WER}
\subsubsection{ABC}
\subsubsection{DEF}
\subsection{ZTR}
\subsubsection{OIU}
\subsubsection{OIZ}
\subsubsection{POI}
\section{YYY}
\subsection{WER}
\subsubsection{EDC}
\subsubsection{RFV}
\subsection{TGB}
\subsubsection{ZHN}
\subsubsection{OUH}
\subsubsection{WEK}
\chapter{ZZZ}
\chapter{AAA}

\end{document}
```

---

Just noticed there is still a problem with hyperref:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}      

\pdfbookmark[1]{Contents}{toc}    
\shorttoc{Contents}{1} 

\pdfbookmark[1]{Contents (detailed)}{toc}    
\shorttoc{Contents (detailed)}{3}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{XXX}
\section{YYY}
\subsection{WER}
\subsubsection{ABC}
\subsubsection{DEF}
\subsection{ZTR}
\subsubsection{OIU}
\subsubsection{OIZ}
\subsubsection{POI}
\section{YYY}
\subsection{WER}
\subsubsection{EDC}
\subsubsection{RFV}
\subsection{TGB}
\subsubsection{ZHN}
\subsubsection{OUH}
\subsubsection{WEK}
\chapter{ZZZ}
\chapter{AAA}

\end{document}
```

By what does {toc} has to be replaced in the second \pdfbookmark? [Sorry, had problem with editing the above comment --> administrator please delete it!]

Comment: *The Tale of two Tables*  "It was the best of Times, it was the worst of Times."  Just ignore me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The package you need is `shorttoc`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{shorttoc}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents (detailed)}

\begin{document}

\shorttoc{Contents}{1} % Only sections

\tableofcontents
```

The important thing is that `\shorttoc` comes *before* `\tableofcontents`; you can specify any depth you want with the second argument.

In case you want to use `hyperref`, then here's how:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents (detailed)}

\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[1]{Contents}{toc}
\shorttoc{Contents}{1}

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[1]{Contents (detailed)}{toc (detailed)}
\tableofcontents
```

Notice that you *don't* have to specify `\shorttoc` for the detailed contents, but only `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Perfect, problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution.

Replace the first `\tableofcontents` with

```
{\expandafter\def\csname @starttoc\endcsname#1{\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.#1}{}{}}%
\tableofcontents}
```

MWE (with `hyperref`)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

{\expandafter\def\csname @starttoc\endcsname#1{\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.#1}{}{}}%
\tableofcontents}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents (detailed)}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{XXX}
\section{YYY}
\subsection{WER}
\subsubsection{ABC}
\subsubsection{DEF}
\subsection{ZTR}
\subsubsection{OIU}
\subsubsection{OIZ}
\subsubsection{POI}
\section{YYY}
\subsection{WER}
\subsubsection{EDC}
\subsubsection{RFV}
\subsection{TGB}
\subsubsection{ZHN}
\subsubsection{OUH}
\subsubsection{WEK}
\chapter{ZZZ}
\chapter{AAA}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How can I change view of chapter in the fist one TOC?

Answer (score 2):

You can use package [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc). No problem with [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}          

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\etocsetnexttocdepth{section}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents (detailed)}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{XXX}
\section{YYY}
\subsection{WER}
\subsubsection{ABC}
\subsubsection{DEF}
\subsection{ZTR}
\subsubsection{OIU}
\subsubsection{OIZ}
\subsubsection{POI}
\section{YYY}
\subsection{WER}
\subsubsection{EDC}
\subsubsection{RFV}
\subsection{TGB}
\subsubsection{ZHN}
\subsubsection{OUH}
\subsubsection{WEK}
\chapter{ZZZ}
\chapter{AAA}

\end{document}
```

The first one:

[image]

The second one:

[image]