# Table of contents is only print once

Tags: table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two tables of content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64359/two-tables-of-content)

I am trying to include two different tables of contents in my latex document:

1. The first one, is a **short table of contents**, that only includes the chapter and section headings. This table is to be included in the "frontmatter" part of the document.
2. The second one, is the **extended table of contents**, that includes all the chapter/section/subsection/subsubsection/paragraph headings of the document. It is to be included in the "backmatter" part of the document.

Since both tables have the same entries, I tried to do that with the following code:

```
\frontmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Short TOC}
\tableofcontents

(... document ...)

\backmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Extended TOC}
\tableofcontents
```

The result is that the table of contents is only printed once. Either in the frontmatter or in the blackmatter, but I could not get it to be printed twice as I need.

Is there an 'easy way' for doing this or do I have to create an additional table of contents in a separated contents file?

Kind regards and thanks in advance for your help, Ricardo.

Comment: The `shorttoc` package should be what you're looking for.