# Two ToCs in a document?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I want to have a first level ToC in the beginning of the document, and full ToC at the end. I'm using `titletoc`.

There's a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48900/two-independent-tocs) but it is actually about printing ToC by parts.

I expected to be able just to call `\tableofcontents` twice in a document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

{
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
  \tableofcontents
}

\section{H1}
\subsection{H2}
\section{H1}
\subsection{H2}
\section{H1}
\subsection{H2}

{
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
  \tableofcontents
}

\end{document}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: what about this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64359/two-tables-of-content

Comment: @touhami: [it works](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228983/8992), thanks. Didn't find that.