# Additional short TOC in scrbook

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Visibly the KOMA class lacks the possibility to add a second, e.g. short, table of contents (TOC), while memoir does as in the following adopted example.
See also [Include Detailed Contents entry in short TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346266/25077)

Nevertheless I want to use it in `scrbook` but then the detailed TOC is not printed.
Does someone know an implementation that works with `pdfpages`?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Short Contents}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
  \tableofcontents
}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}
\section{Sub A}
\section{Sub B}
\end{document}
```

#### Comment

The use of the package `pdfpages` (with `addtotoc=...`) seems to be incompatible with `etoc`, which itself could serve as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use KOMA-Script package `scrwfile`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrwfile}
\TOCclone[Short Contents]{toc}{stoc}
\addtocontents{stoc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=0}% or \BeforeStartingTOC[stoc]{\value{tocdepth}=0}
\begin{document}
\listofstoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Intro}
\section{Sub A}
\section{Sub B}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is patching `\addtocentrydefault` to write all ToC entries in a new file with the extension `.stoc`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addtotoclist[\jobname]{stoc}
\BeforeStartingTOC[stoc]{\value{tocdepth}=0}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault
  {\addxcontentsline{stoc}{#1}[#2]{#3}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\listoftoc[Short Contents]{stoc}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Intro}
\section{Sub A}
\section{Sub B}
\addchap{Test}
\end{document}
```

If the TOC should get an entry in the "Short Contents" add the following lines to the preamble of the examples above:

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{%
  \addxcontentsline{stoc}{chapter}{\protect\contentsname}%
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the technique from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228983). As you want it to work with babel you have to take care of babel commands.

It seems that including babel will also break the grouping of `tocdepth`, so you might need to `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` before issuing your second `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
{
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Short Contents}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
  \expandafter\def\csname @starttoc\endcsname#1{\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.#1}{}{}}\tableofcontents
\makeatother
}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}
\section{Sub A}
\section{Sub B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution seems incompatible with the package `babel`. Try with `\usepackage[english]{babel}`.

Comment: @strpeter No, it is not. You only have to take care of the obvious babel commands.

Comment: True it works! Great thank you. Could you explain a bit more in depth what the following command does? `\expandafter\def\csname @starttoc\endcsname#1{\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.#1}{}{}}`

Comment: @strpeter `\@starttoc` is the core piece of `\tableofcontents` and it is simply redefined to input the toc file if it exists. As it is now in a makeatletter context one would not even need the expandafter-csname magic here…

Comment: @strpeter A much better explanation and workaround is given in Schweinbacke's answer.

Answer (score 3):

To read the `toc`-file twice, you have to avoid to open it to write before the second reading. LaTeX's kernel macro `\@starttoc`, which is used by `\tableoofcontents`, usually also opens the file for writing. Loading `scrwfile` as shown in [esdd's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467905/9057) already avoids opening files for writing when `\@starttoc` is used. Also local redefinition of `\@starttoc` as show in [TeXnician's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467903/9057) can be used to avoid the opening for writing. Another suggestion would be to deactivate LaTeX's opening of auxiliary files for writing, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrwfile}
\usepackage{mwe}% provides \Blinddocument
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\shorttableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup
    \value{tocdepth}=\z@ % set tocdepth locally to zero
    \@fileswfalse % deactivate opening of auxiliary files
    \listoftoc[Short Contents]{\ext@toc}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\shorttableofcontents% must be before \tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Here KOMA-Script's `\listoftoc` is used to show the short version of the ToC. See the manual for more information.

However this suggestion would fail, if `\shorttableofcontents` would be used after `\tableofcontents`! And you cannot add extra entries to the short table of contents, that are not shown in the normal table of contents. If you need such things, esdd's answer would be the better suggestion.

However you could use another KOMA-Script macro to clone the main ToC:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrwfile}
\usepackage{mwe}% provides \Blinddocument
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  listname={Short Contents},
]{stoc}
\makeatletter  
\renewcommand{\addtocentrydefault}[3]{%
  \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@toc}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \tocbasic@addxcontentsline{stoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother
\BeforeStartingTOC[stoc]{\value{tocdepth}=0\relax}
\let\shorttableofcontents\listofstocs
\begin{document}
\shorttableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

KOMA-Script uses `\addtocentrydefault` to generate the ToC entries of all headings. But this does not work, if a package generates ToC entries without using `\addtocentryefault` e.g. using `\addcontentsline` directly.

Instead of redefining `\addtocentrydefault` you can try to patch it as shown in esdd's second suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

ah sorry, posted this before seeing your `pdfpages` comment. Maybe this should be topic of another question if there is incompatibility with `etoc`? (a mwe showing the problem would be helpful)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Short Contents}
  \etocsetnexttocdepth{chapter}
  \tableofcontents
}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}
\section{Sub A}
\section{Sub B}
\end{document}
```